# Typo3 LTS9 PDF dimensions are not read and displayed in 0x0

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, typo3, typo3-9.x

I am having an issue with PDF's in the latest Typo3 release. If I add PDF to the Image content element, I get this:

[image]

The file info looks like this:

[image]

Checking the Image Processing Test of Typo3, no errors are returned. PDF/AI also seems to be fine.

[image]

I tested several PDF's and AI files as well, they won't show dimensions either.

I have the suspicion that the command 'identify' does not work within Typo3, it still returns perfect results from shell.

Any idea where to look?

Comment: Strictly said PDFs do not have a fixed resolution in pixels as they are a vector format. Bitmaps may be embedded, but their pixels can be subject to an arbitrary affine transformation.

Comment: I can finally say that the problem is not with Imagemagick/ghostscript. As the Image Processing Test Tool indicates, everything works fine. The first confusion comes from TYPO3 LTS9, as compared to LTS8 the rendering of  PDF Filelink thumbnails does not work anymore. Adding a PDF filelink creates a thumbnail in the BE preview, but does not in the FE. The second confusion still remains the 0x0 dimensions of PDF in filelist. In older TYPO3 version, dimensions where shown for PDFs as well.

Comment: some time ago we had a similar problem: we did not get any metadata from PDFs. Our solution: remove GM and install GM after ghostscript. with that solution we got metadata.

Answer (score 1):

multiple reasons possible:

1. you just need to reimport metadata (scheduler task)
2. your PDF is coded in an unsual format (there is more then one option in PDF to include the title image)
3. missing/wrong rights:
   maybe another program is executed from commandline than from PHP.
   maybe the file can't be accessed correctly from ghostscript started from web

Comment: all 3 options are ok and won't solve the issue with 0x0 pixels and PDF link thumbnail